# Serve Static content to subdomain with express?

Tags: node.js, express, server, subdomain

I have an express app, which is just the default blank app. I have then added the line:

```
app.use(serveStatic('docs/public', {'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm']}))
```

to serve the contents of my `docs/public` directory. This works great, but it is being served to the root of my application, so I no longer see the default express index page.

I would like to see the static html (which I am currently seeing as my index) as a subdomain, e.g. blog.mydomain.com. Or at least as mydomain.com/blog. How do I serve the static content to a subdomain?

NB: the static file names and folders can't change, as my ./docs directory is a hexo project and any changes would break the generation of the static content in the docs/public folder.

I have tried to use `express-subdomain` so I added code like this to my app.js:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.use(serveStatic('docs/public', {'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm']}))

app.use(subdomain('docs', router));
```

However, If I run that, I get the express index page at `http://localhost:3000/` (not the static one) which is what I want, but if I go to `http://docs.localhost:3000/` then I don't get my static content, still the original express index. In fact, if I remove the subdomain code nd run the app, navigate tot he docs subdomain I still get the same result.

I have also tried to use the subdomain module:

```
app.use(subdomain('docs', serveStatic('docs/public', {'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm']})));
```

However, that has the same result as above (not serving any static content).

So how can I serve the static content I am currently serving on a subdomain?

Comment: Have you looked at [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain)?

Comment: @OmarDarwish yes, but I couldn't work out how to use it. See my question update.

Answer (score 1):

@GeorgeEdwards In your example code you've called the static middleware before the subdomain middleware. The order is important... it should be something like this:

```
app.use(subdomain('docs', express.static('docs/public')));
```

This means any requests with the `docs` subdomain will be handled by the express static middleware.

Comment: I am afraid with this line, I still get the same result (docs.localhost:3000 routes to the same page as localhost:3000 - not my static content) here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/71371bc7004aaac850c00c384cbea2f7) of my `app.js` file